# How to go out of a folder when directing in java web

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page, where I'm checking rather or not a user, has a valid user session in order to access customer pages, the problem is when I try to redirect the customer to my index/login page, it includes my WEB-INF folder, where all my other files or located.

Here is my isValidUser.jsp:

```
<html>
<%
    User u = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    if(u == null){
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
%>
</html>
```

Here is how i include it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Find carport</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%@include file ="header.jsp" %>
    <%@include file="isValidUser.jsp" %>
    <h1>Start din ordre</h1><br>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives the error: `"HTTP Status 404 - /LogInSample/WEB-INF/index.jsp"` because it thinks my index page is in my WEB-INF folder, how can I prevent this?

Comment: where the index.jsp file is actually located in your project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using path which is relative to your servlet.

From documentation of [ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)):

> The pathname specified may be relative, although it cannot extend outside the current servlet context. **If the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root.** This method returns null if the servlet container cannot return a RequestDispatcher.

This is what you need

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

All servlets after compilation go to **WEB-INF/classes**, so your code trying to find your **index.jsp** under WEB-INF folder because it's relative to your servlet and not to the context root.

P.S: I'm assuming that your index.jsp right under context root, but if it's in some folder under context root you need to specify the folder in path too.